# Is there grammar or lexer and parser for Python (or subset), written in PLY?

Tags: python, parsing, ply

Is there grammar or lexer and parser for Python (or subset), written in PLY?

Comment: Have you checked the PyPy stuff?

Comment: PyPy uses its own parser, not PLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it myself:
[python4ply](http://dalkescientific.com/Python/python4ply.html)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not exactly what you were looking for, but Jeremy Seik at the University of Colorado Boulder runs [ECEN 4543 - Introduction to Compilers](http://ecee.colorado.edu/ecen4553) that uses a combination of the python AST module and ply to build up larger and larger subsets of python, and uses the results to produce native code. Course notes are available from [here](http://ecee.colorado.edu/ecen4553/fall10/notes.pdf).

An impressive tutorial based on that class was given at PyCon 2010, entitled ["How to Compile Python x86 Assembly, the Python Way"](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/3263942)